# How to fix game loop running at different framerate than VSync?

Tags: opengl, language-agnostic

For example, I have 60 fps for game logic but 50 fps for VSync. Should I move game loop into a different thread and send drawing requests for drawing thread or I can still fix this with one thread?

Answer (score 2):

Does your game logic take 1s/60 to compute or is this just the simulation interval you use? In case of it being an interval I suggest you adjust the simulation intervals by the time it took to display a frame each, i.e. you measure the time between frames and feed your simulation with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use a timer than hard-coded timing. (Rather use the difference between the previous update and current update than 1/60 seconds.) That avoid situations where computations that can not keep up at 60fps. Then VSync won't be an issue also.

Correct me if I am wrong, but you can render at any fps and the screen draw at any other fps without any issues (except maybe a little bit of jitter)

With multi-core CPUs, I recommend rather use thread where practical. For example physics in one thread, and render in another (Render with snap-shot data to prevent side-effects).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article by Glenn Fiedler, "Fix your timestep":

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/